# Invoke the graph REST API from a SharePoint XAML workflow

Tags: xaml, azure, sharepoint-2013

I want to use the graph API (graph.windows.net) in a XAML Workflow that I create in Visual Studio

I have taken this article as the basis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx

The picture below shows the simplest form of the workflow

[image]

I have registered my App in Azure AD (so I have clientID and callback URLs)

From other OAuth projects I have learned the "OAuth Dance".
I need a way to get the Bearer token.

My question is: how do I perform this oauth dance in a XAML Workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I spend some more time researching:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

This is do-able in a workflow step:

First do a Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials parse the JSON result and next do the actual service call.

No need for the dance, since it is service to service :-)